# Django Heroku: Adding secret key to heroku does not work

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to add my SECRET_KEY environment variable to heroku using the command:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='mysecretkey'
```

The command won't even be executed because it says to a part of my secret key

> "cannot be processed syntactically at this point"

(it may be a bit different in english, my command line runs in german. That's just my translation).

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, the problem remains. It seems to have an issue with the "@" symbol in my secret key.

Comment: If the issue is a character in your command line, try setting the environment variable in web interface. Log in heroku.com, find Settings -> config vars -> reveal config vars and you'll be able to set it using web form.